# On some rational points on an elliptic curve over finite field

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, finite-fields

Let $p\equiv3\pmod4$ be a prime. We consider the elliptic curve $E$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$
(in affine coordinates) defined by
$$y^2=x^3+x.$$
Clearly the discriminant of $E$ is $-2^6$. And it is known that
$$ \mid\{(x,y):0<x,y<p,\ y^2\equiv x^3+x\pmod p\}\mid=p-1, $$
where $\mid S\mid$ is the cardinality of a set $S$.
However, it seems not obvious to get the explicic value of
$$\mid\{(x,y): 0<x<p/2,0<y<p, y^2\equiv x^3+x \pmod p\}\mid.$$
Are there any references on this topic? Your comments are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: This looks like a homework question.  If you want a hint, consider the action of the automorphism $(x,y)\mapsto(-x,\sqrt{-1}y)$ (which is *not* defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$).